# Linux recursively replace periods for all directorys and all but last period for files with underscores

Tags: regex, linux, file, rename, period

I have the following command which recursively renames all the files/directory's to lowercase and replaces spaces with _.

```
find . -iname "*" |  rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/; s/ /_/g;'
```

How do I extend it to remove all periods from directories and leave just the last period for files?

So input would be:
this.is.a.directory
this.is.a.file.txt

Output
this_is_a_directory
this_is_a_file.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `find` in a while loop and using a regex to leave last `DOT` for files:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' entry; do
   entry="${entry#./}"         # strip ./
   if [[ -d $entry ]]; then
      rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/; s/ /_/g; s/\./_/g' "$entry"
   else
      rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/; s/ /_/g; s/\.(?=.*\.)/_/g' "$entry"
   fi
done < <(find . -iname '*' -print0)
```

`s/\.(?=.*\.)/_/g` will only replace a DOT if there is another DOT ahead in the input.

Comment: When I run the above command it throws an error - Can't rename ./this.is.a.test _/this_is_a.test: No such file or directory.  Any Ideas why It throws this error?

Comment: I think that is because `./` at the start. Try my edited script now.